# How can I keep Flex events from being dispatched to the target?

Tags: apache-flex

I'd like to avoid that mouse events triggered by the user don't get dispatched to their target objects, effectively "freezing" the GUI for the user.

In a sample application featuring just a single [`mx.controls.Button`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html) I called [`addEventListener`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) on the button to get notified of [mouse events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html). In the event handler, I called [`Event::stopImmediatePropagation`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29) on the event, assuming that this would "discard" the event. Clicking the button would call my event handler, but yet the button was "clicked" (it animated and triggered an event).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
button.mouseEnabled = false;
button.mouseChildren = false;
```

should work

Comment: Hm, interesting - I could set those properties from within my event listener (so before the target receives the event)? I guess that it means that I have to memorize the objects on which I disabled mouse interactions, so that I can re-enable it once I unfreeze the GUI?

Comment: No, you should do it before clicking. Do you need just to disable the button? Or is there something else?

Comment: I'd like to disable a lot more objects - in fact, I'd like to disable all objects except a few special ones. I guess I could just traverse the object hierarchy and do this to all objects, but I wonder whether this could be a performance problem...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how advanced your interface is, you could just throw an object (s:Rect in an s:Group would work) on top of everything, set width and height to 100%, and disable mouseChildren

Answer (score 0):

USE removeEventListener()

```
var b:Button = new Button();

function init():void
{
    b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
}


function onButtonClick(event:MourseEvent):void
{ 
    b.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
}
```

Comment: or if you do not have b declared as global variable, use event.target.removeEventListener(...);